# How do I remove an Event Listener and replace it with a new one?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

I am making a multiple choice quiz. When I remove an Event Listener, I can't seem to replace it with a new Event Listener.

See my code below...

```
choiceC.removeEventListener('click', firstQuestion());

choiceC.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    question.appendChild(feedback);
});

choiceB.removeEventListener('click', firstQuestion());

// Correct Answer
choiceB.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    thirdQuestion();
});
```

choiceC was the previous correct choice that moves the user to the next question. I want to replace this Event Listener with feedback that the user's choice is wrong. choiceB is the new correct answer. I want to remove the Event Listener that previously notified that the user's choice was wrong and replace it with a function that moves to the next question.

See my GitHub repository for the complete HTML, CSS and JavaScript files: https://github.com/billyhao12/Code-Quiz

Thanks in advance to anyone who helps.

Comment: Functions like `addEventListener()` and `removeEventListener()` require a function *reference* to be passed to them. It looks like you are calling `firstQuestion()` inline and passing the returned result to `removeEventListener()`. You should probably reference `firstQuestion`, not `firstQuestion()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a reference to the function hence:

```
choiceC.addEventListener('click', firstQuestion);

choiceC.removeEventListener('click', firstQuestion);

// your new function replacing the firstQuestion func
choiceC.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    question.appendChild(feedback);
});
```